# As3: Tile collision not firing (flashpunk)

Tags: actionscript-3, types, entity, collision, tile

I have this code on a game I am making:

```
override public function update():void
    {
        var pressed:Boolean = false;

        if (collide("ground", x, y))
        {
            trace("COLLISION");
        }

        if (Input.check(Key.LEFT))
        {
            xSpeed -= power;
            pressed = true;
        }

        if (Input.check(Key.RIGHT))
        {
            xSpeed += power;
            pressed = true;
        }

        if (collide("ground", x, y + 1))
        {
            onTheGround = true;
            ySpeed = 0;

            if (Input.check(Key.UP))
            {
                ySpeed -= jumpPower;
            }
        } else {

            ySpeed += gravity;
        }

        if (Math.abs(xSpeed) < 1 && !pressed)
        {
            xSpeed = 0;
        }

        xSpeed *= hFriction;
        ySpeed *= vFriction;

        adjustXPosition();
        adjustYPosition();
    }
```

And then I have some tiles on the map generated by this class:

```
public class Level1 extends Entity
{
    private var _tiles:Tilemap;
    private var _grid:Grid;

    public function Level1() 
    {
        _tiles = new Tilemap(Assets.SPRITE_TILESET, 1920, 1080, 120, 120);
        graphic = _tiles;
        layer = 1;

        _tiles.setRect(0, 0, 1920 / 120, 1080 / 120, 1);
        _tiles.setRect(0, 17, 1920 / 120, 1, 0);

        _grid = new Grid(1920, 1080, 120, 120, 0, 0);
        mask = _grid;

        _grid.setRect(0, 17, 1920 / 120, 1, true);

        type = "ground";
    }
}
```

But when the player touches on the ground, no collision is detected! And the player just falls through it! What is it that is wrong? I thought "type" was gonna make it work, but I guess I was wrong..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (collide("ground", x, y))
```

i think you shouldn't use "x,y" instead of "0,0" because this parameters aren't for position of collision, if i remember right, it is for offset of collision as optional.

so, when you use x,y for this parameters, it may be meaning x+x,y+y as position.

so here,

```
(collide("ground", x, y + 1))
```

you should use

```
(collide("ground", 0, 1))
```

i'm not sure about that, but you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give your player a proper HitBox?  It looks like your Level1 class is set up properly, but you didn't include the code for your player's hitbox.

You can give your player a basic hitbox like so:

```
 player.setHitbox(64, 64, 0, 0);
```